# Hidden ViewModel Property defaulting to 0 when null - should stay null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

Get Controller Method:

```
    public ActionResult Create(int? parentId)
    {
        var model = new CreatePersonViewModel();

        // pull set from db
        var parent = _db.Persons.FirstOrDefault(s => s.PersonId == parentId);

        if (parent != null)
        {
            model.ParentId = parent.PersonId;
        }

        return View("Create", model);
    }
```

POST:

```
public ActionResult Create(CreatePersonViewModel viewModel) // viewModel.ParentId is 0 when it's passed to this method from the view, even though I didn't set it, and it's null coming from GET.  
        {
            //bla bla
        }
```

My View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>CreatePersonViewModel</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ParentId) // tried with second parameter of "null" as well

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

Any idea why the view is sending back a value of 0 in that property for cases when it should be null?   I don't have any details to add here but the form validation is asking for more text so here it is.

Comment: is it always null? also, please share your model.

Comment: I assume ParentId on your ViewModel is nullable?

Comment: Funny how you share everything *BUT* the thing that matters for getting a good answer - the model.

Comment: I'm an idiot.  Forgot the question mark on the property.  Thanks rob

Comment: @user2062383, we've all been there